# running js file for mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I wrote a small js file that should list all the DBs in a current MongoDB instance and find a document in one of them (db = database, collection = col)

test.js

```
print(db.getMongo().getDBs())
db.getSiblingDB('database')
out = db.col.findOne()
print(out)
```

However, the output is

```
# mongo test.js

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
[object Object]
null
```

What am I missing?

Cheers, M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

```js
printjson(db.getMongo().getDBs());
var db = db.getSiblingDB('database');
var out = db.col.findOne();
printjson(out);
```

You probably won't see the output you want unless you use `printjson`. Also `.getSiblingDB()` **returns** the database object, so you need to "set" the variable.

Finally, "always" use `var` to avoid the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) "evaluating" each line. Which is also what you likely do not want.